# What is Ground Electrode in EMG?

Tags: operational-amplifier

*Learning about EMG as a part of our research. My team has at least some experience with electronics that is worth mentioning, but don't have any experience with EMG/bio-potentials. Most EMG hardware is designed without a ground electrode, but an engineer basically recommended using a ground electrode as well "like used in EEG".

What is ground electrode in EMG and what do the circuit design(s) look like? Can any operational amplifier be used?

Any recommended resources that outline the design of such hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Many analog front-ends have quite a narrow input common-mode voltage range. The front-ends are themselves differential, but the common-mode range is limited.

So, these front-ends *require* that their supply rails are kept within the common mode range from the absolute bio-potential measured.

Using a ground electrode is *one means* of ensuring that the front-end supplies end up where they need to be in absolute voltage terms relative to the bio-potentials on the electrodes.

Now it's also clear that the "ground" aspect of that electrode is a misnomer. Whether the electrode is connected to the GND node of the front-end is dictated by the front-end design, and is not any sort of an absolute requirement. Yes, the common name is "ground electrode", but its purpose has nothing to do with ground. Calling it a "potential equalization" electrode would be truer to its purpose. Such equalization *can be achieved by other means*, so a separate electrode for that purpose is just one way to go about it. It's good to keep that in mind.

> What is ground electrode in EMG

It is *one* possible means of keeping the input signals within a narrow common-mode range of the particular front-end in use. It is the front-end parameters that may require this.

---

There were active surface EMG electrodes available even in the late 70s/early 80s that were isolated enough that there was no need for ground electrodes. The front-end's leakage would rise as the inputs neared common mode limits, and the system was "self-centering". Each active differential electrode was isolated from all the others. They used 4.5V or 6V power from 3-4 hearing aid batteries. The front-end was CMOS, output was phase modulated onto a carrier and inductively coupled. The electrodes were hermetic and disposable. The output cable latched onto the electrode case with a magnet pulling on an internal steel element in the electrode. That magnet also turned on a reed relay that switched power on the preamp and modulator in the electrode. The carrier amplitude was proportional to the battery voltage, so one coil carried both the signal and battery status feedback. That was 45 years ago. Today the same can be done with a 1.5V supply, capacitive coupling, and battery lifetimes measured in weeks of active use :) Of course it takes an analog ASIC done in a low-voltage analog CMOS process. The solution from half the century ago used off-the-shelf chip dies, no ASICs.

That's just an example of let's say lateral thinking in this area. Today it's even easier - that stuff was super expensive to make back then.